# ValueError: invalid literal for float() after excepting ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I still get a:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 002Q
```

when I try to:

```
df.column_name.astype(np.float64)
```

even after doing this on my column:

```
def convert_float(x):
    try:
        return np.float64(x)
    except ValueError:
        return np.NaN

df.column_name.apply(convert_float).astype(np.float64)
```

I also looked in the data manually, but could not find any value `002Q`

Comment: can you try `df['column_name'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column_name'], errors='coerce')` also you must have that string value in your column what does `df.loc[df['column_name'].str.contains('002Q'), 'column_name']` show?

Comment: Could it be something weird in there like a list, complex number, etc.  I would maybe check the types with something like: `for i in range(len(df)): if type( df.ix[i,'column_name'] ) != str : print(i,'not string')`

Comment: Thanks. The second tip helped me to identify an inconsistent line. `to_numeric()` wasn't applicable, since I have to use pandas 0.16.2.